# Only the collision portion of the cloth sim is being simulated

Tags: cloth-simulation

I was preparing to rig a dress to a character model, but when I added a cloth modifier, something strange happened: The cloth mesh would receive a collision impulse when touching a collider object, but no actual cloth simulation would occur. This results in parts of the mesh moving in the direction of the collision, but without any cloth physics. I should also note that this only happens to the dress object (or any duplicates). all other objects behave as expected when given a cloth modifier.

Some things I have tried (which didn't fix the problem):

- Removing duplicate vertices (there were none)
- Removing all other modifiers
- Removing all vertex groups
- Clearing all unused data blocks
- Unparenting the object from the armature
- Making a copy of the object
- Manually sifting through the object/mesh data for any anomalies (I could have missed some though)
- Restarting Blender
- Restarting my computer
- Using a newer Blender version

Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

In edit mode, select "Mesh > Clean Up > Degenerate Dissolve" This removes any edges with length 0, which I had one of in my model. Why this single edge had such a strange effect on the cloth sim is still unknown.